# How to write parametric/generic functions in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, types, spring-webflux, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to find a workaround to make a `Spring Reactive Webclient` work with `JDBC`.
Here is were I got the idea from: https://gitorko.github.io/2019/04/02/Spring-Webflux-Reactive-JDBC/.

I'm writing a `service` that calls the jdbc repository interface and instead of returning the type of my domain object `MyClass` returns a `Mono<MyClass>` like this:

```
//other specific imports here
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers
import java.util.concurrent.Callable

@Service
class MyClassService(val repo: MyClassRepository, val jdbcScheduler: Scheduler){

    fun save(obj: MyClass?): Mono<MyClass?>? {
       return asyncCallable { repo.save(obj) }
    }

    protected fun <S> asyncCallable(callable: Callable<S>?): Mono<S>? {
        return Mono.fromCallable(callable).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).publishOn(jdbcScheduler)
    }
}

//this is a jdbc repository
interface MyClassRepository : CrudRepository<MyClass, UUID> {}
```

Now the problem is that calling `asyncCallable { repo.save(obj) }` returns the compile error `inferred type is MyClass? but TypeVariable(S) was expected` and `Mono.fromCallable(callable).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).publishOn(jdbcScheduler)` returns the compile error `inferred type is Callable<S>? but Callable<out TypeVariable(T)!> was expected`.
I understand by reading about kotlin generics that this has to do with the variance. If I'm not wrong the function `asyncCallable`is invariant on the generic type `S`and in this case covariance is required?

Comment: side note: using parallel scheduler for blocking operation is a bad idea, use elastic Scheduler or some custom scheduler instead

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you need is `asyncCallable(Callable { repo.save(obj) })`.

Complete example:

```
@Service
class MyClassService(val repo: MyClassRepository, val jdbcScheduler: Scheduler){

    fun save(obj: MyClass): Mono<MyClass?>? {
        return asyncCallable(Callable { repo.save(obj) })
    }

    protected fun <S> asyncCallable(callable: Callable<S>): Mono<S>? {
        return Mono.fromCallable(callable).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).publishOn(jdbcScheduler)
    }
}
```

I'd also remove the `?`s, but I left them to keep it as close to your code as possible.